# Extract files inside folder in ZIP archive to current folder

Tags: zip, unzip

can I extract files from a specific folder inside a zip archive
to a current folder?

I tried to use

```
unzip archive.zip folder/*
```

But I got folder "folder" in my current directory. 
How can I extract files in "folder" to current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by

```
unzip archive.zip folder/*; mv folder/* .;rm -r folder
```

I don't think there is an option in `unzip` to do it directly.

To make it shorter

```
f=folder; unzip archive.zip $f; mv $f .;rm -r $f
```

Or as a script

```
#!/bin/sh
unzip $1 $2
mv $2 .
rm -r $2
```

Run as `script.sh archive.zip folder`.

Answer (score 5):

According to the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59276/how-to-extract-only-a-specific-folder-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory) you can do it with single quotes `'` around the folder you want to extract.  Use `-j` for junk paths which means the archive's directory structure is not recreated.  Use `-d` to specify what folder you want it extracted to.  Below is shown extracting a folder with `1992` in the folder name from an archive that has multiple folders contained with in by running this line:

```
unzip -j archive.zip 'folder/to/extract/*' -d 'where/to/extract/to/'
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/media/500GB$ unzip -l Holiday\ Lemmings\ Pack
Archive:  Holiday Lemmings Pack.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2004-10-07 23:39   Holiday Lemmings 1993/
     3597  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/ADLIB.DAT
      252  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/GREET.DAT
     1056  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/GROUND1O.DAT
     1056  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/GROUND2O.DAT
    16157  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/INSTALL.EXE
     3143  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/LEVEL000.DAT
     2868  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/LEVEL001.DAT
     3033  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/LEVEL002.DAT
     5654  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/LEVEL003.DAT
    59775  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/MAIN.DAT
     3560  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/TANDYSND.DAT
    25902  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/VGAGR1.DAT
    33123  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/VGAGR2.DAT
    31520  1993-11-11 11:11   Holiday Lemmings 1993/VGALEMMI.EXE
        0  2004-10-07 23:39   Holiday Lemmings 1994/
     6894  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/ADLIB.DAT
      438  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/GREET.DAT
     1056  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/GROUND1O.DAT
     1056  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/GROUND2O.DAT
       38  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEMMINGS.BAT
     2432  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL000.DAT
     2633  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL001.DAT
     3433  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL002.DAT
     3401  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL003.DAT
     3143  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL004.DAT
     2868  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL005.DAT
     3033  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL006.DAT
     5654  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/LEVEL007.DAT
    58577  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/MAIN.DAT
     5470  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/TANDYSND.DAT
    25902  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/VGAGR1.DAT
    33123  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/VGAGR2.DAT
    31610  1995-07-04 14:20   Holiday Lemmings 1994/VGALEMMI.EXE
        0  2004-10-07 23:39   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/
     3597  1991-12-03 14:19   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/ADLIB.DAT
     8164  1991-12-07 14:47   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/CLOSING.EXE
     1056  1991-11-11 16:13   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/GROUND0O.DAT
     1056  1991-12-03 10:08   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/GROUND2O.DAT
    11057  1991-12-03 14:51   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/INSTALL.EXE
      756  1991-11-14 09:26   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/LEMMINGS.BAT
     2552  1991-12-03 17:40   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/LEVEL000.DAT
    59992  1991-12-03 15:24   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/MAIN.DAT
     8602  1991-12-07 14:45   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/OPENING.EXE
     3560  1991-12-03 14:25   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/TANDYSND.DAT
    28701  1991-12-03 17:44   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/TGAL.EXE
       74  1991-12-05 18:16   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/TGALEMMI.BAT
    15981  1991-12-03 10:26   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/TGAMAIN.DAT
    17957  1991-11-29 11:43   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/VGAGR0.DAT
    33123  1991-11-29 11:44   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/VGAGR2.DAT
    30469  1991-12-03 17:44   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/VGAL.EXE
       74  1991-12-05 18:16   X-Mas Lemmings 1991/VGALEMMI.BAT
        0  2004-10-07 23:39   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/
     3597  1991-12-03 14:19   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/ADLIB.DAT
    10126  1992-11-30 11:31   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/CLOSING.EXE
     1056  1991-12-03 10:08   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/GROUND2O.DAT
       28  1992-10-29 15:04   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/HELP.BAT
      492  1991-07-24 14:00   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/INSTALL.BAT
      763  1992-10-29 15:03   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/LEMMINGS.BAT
     2201  1992-11-25 11:55   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/LEVEL000.DAT
    59992  1991-12-03 15:24   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/MAIN.DAT
    16153  1991-12-03 14:51   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/MENU.EXE
     8733  1992-11-30 11:29   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/OPENING.EXE
     3560  1991-12-03 14:25   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/TANDYSND.DAT
    33123  1991-11-29 11:44   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/VGAGR2.DAT
    30469  1991-12-03 17:44   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/VGAL.EXE
       77  1992-11-30 11:36   X-Mas Lemmings 1992/VGALEMMI.BAT
---------                     -------
   778598                     67 files
```

All I want to extract is the folder with `1992` in the name to a folder named `1992/`:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/media/500GB$ unzip -j Holiday\ Lemmings\ Pack.zip '*1992/*' -d '1992/'
Archive:  Holiday Lemmings Pack.zip
  inflating: 1992/ADLIB.DAT          
  inflating: 1992/CLOSING.EXE        
  inflating: 1992/GROUND2O.DAT       
 extracting: 1992/HELP.BAT           
  inflating: 1992/INSTALL.BAT        
  inflating: 1992/LEMMINGS.BAT       
  inflating: 1992/LEVEL000.DAT       
  inflating: 1992/MAIN.DAT           
  inflating: 1992/MENU.EXE           
  inflating: 1992/OPENING.EXE        
  inflating: 1992/TANDYSND.DAT       
  inflating: 1992/VGAGR2.DAT         
  inflating: 1992/VGAL.EXE           
  inflating: 1992/VGALEMMI.BAT       
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/media/500GB$ cd 1992/
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/media/500GB/1992$ ls
ADLIB.DAT     HELP.BAT      LEVEL000.DAT  OPENING.EXE   VGALEMMI.BAT
CLOSING.EXE   INSTALL.BAT   MAIN.DAT      TANDYSND.DAT  VGAL.EXE
GROUND2O.DAT  LEMMINGS.BAT  MENU.EXE      VGAGR2.DAT
```

Comment: This is a great answer.